# Encode and decode a mp3 file

Tags: python

I want so save a mp3 file as encoded string in a text file, but it doesn't work with my code

```
import sys, base64

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
b = base64.b64encode(f.read())
print sys.getsizeof(b)
f.close()

try:
    file = open(sys.argv[2] + '.txt', 'w')
    file.write(b)
    file.close()
except:
    print('Something went wrong!')
    sys.exit(0)

f = open(sys.argv[2] + '.txt', 'r').read()
b = base64.b64decode(f)
f.close()

try:
    file = open(sys.argv[2] + '2.mp3', 'w')
    file.write(b)
    file.close()
except:
    print('Something went wrong!')
    sys.exit(0)
```

The encoded string is too short for being the full string, so there isn't a good result. So why "doesn't" it work?

Comment: You need to call `open` using `'rb'`, because it's binary.  Use `len` instead of `sys.getsizeof`.  And is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I've reached my personal goal.

As *pentadecagon* has mentioned:

> You need to call open using 'rb', because it's binary. Use len instead of sys.getsizeof.

```
f = open(sys.argv[2] + '.txt', 'r').read()
b = base64.b64decode(f)
f.close()
```

I changed this to

```
f = open(sys.argv[2] + '.txt', 'r')
b = base64.b64decode(f.read())
f.close()
```

So I've changed it and when I finally create the mp3 file again, you need to write binary 'wb'
and it works.